# Is $Ax = (\alpha_1 x_1, \alpha_2 x_2, \alpha_3 x_3, \dots, \alpha_k x_k, 0, 0, \dots)$ a compact operator?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Is the operator $A$ defined by

$$Ax = (\alpha_1 x_1, \alpha_2 x_2, \alpha_3 x_3, \dots, \alpha_k x_k, 0, 0, \dots)$$

a compact operator?

It only has finitely non-zero dimensions, so does this mean it can be considered to be of finite dimension and hence compact?

Comment: Yes, that is the basic idea. I'm assuming you're working in a normed space?

Comment: Yes I'm in a normed space. Why does that make it ok? $A$ has infinite dimensions, why can we can consider it to be of finite dimensions just because all but finitely many dimensions map to $0$?

Comment: You have a sequence space. I would be concerned about the specifics of that sequence space, except that the range of $A$ is finite-dimensional. The specifics of the norm won't matter so long as the coordinate evaluations are continuous. One could infer that to be the case here, based on the fact that you're presenting the sequence elements to be a topological basis. Then $A$ will be bounded with finite rank range. That's enough for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the domain and range of the the operator $A$.

For a linear operator $A : X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces, one can show that if $A$ is bounded and of finite rank, i.e., $\dim A(X) < \infty$, then the operator $A$ is compact.

So, if you consider normed spaces, then your reasoning is fine.